# Sorting table with rowspans

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

Is there a way to sort a table with multiple rowspans? I was trying a plugin in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1731/), but it seems age does not get sorted correctly. Is there a way to sort an HTML table with  rowspans? I need to have this table sorted with rowspan.

**HTML**

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle">AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="expand-child">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('table').tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like your "expand-child" class. If you remove that, then it seems to sort just fine. What is that class doing?

Comment: If you double click on the sort button, the table breaks without that class

Comment: You mean that the column expands??? That's because the colspan in your tr...is that necessary?

Answer (score -1):

Use Data-tables, it has all functionality: https://datatables.net/

```
$('.tablesorter').DataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": [ 0, 2 ],
    "orderable": false
  } ]
});
```